# How to resolve : Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server Connection to http://localhost:10080 refused

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am new to IBM Worklight Studio , I installed it and trying to deploy the HelloWorklight app on Worklight Server . The problem is the server isn't starting and the following message is displayed :

[**`[2017-09-06 13:56:00] Deploying application 'HelloWorklight' with all environments to Worklight Server... 
[2017-09-06 13:58:17]Failed to deploy application 'HelloWorklight' to Worklight Server: Connection to http://localhost:10080 refused`**
][1]

[and I get this dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73eby.png)

What Should I do to fix this problem to run my project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Connection to http://localhost:10080 refused" .
This seems to suggest there is some firewall or antivirus blocking your local connections. Verify if there are any such restrictions and remove it if required.

Comment: It finally worked, in jvm.options file in the server configuration I added the following line :    -Dos.name=Windows10